# Duplicate user created with Devise gem despite having uniqueness validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, duplicates

I have a rails 4 app that uses devise gem for authentication.
I have a validates_uniqueness_of :email check in user.rb

Despite this check I am seeing duplicate entries being created in the users table.

Weird part is these duplicate entries are created at the time of sign in. For the user signing in.

I am calling an after_action to update a field post login like so - 
This is in the sessions_controller.rb -

```rb
after_action :update_login_terms_and_privacy_accepted_at, only: [:create]

def create
    if params[:user][:terms_and_condition].present? && params[:user][:terms_and_condition]=="0"
      self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
      reset_session
      flash[:error] = "Please accept our terms and conditions"
      redirect_to new_user_session_url
    elsif Rails.env.production? && !verify_recaptcha
      self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
      reset_session
      flash[:error] = "Incorrect Captcha. Please try Again"
      redirect_to new_user_session_url
    else
      if current_user.try(:is_allowed_enterprise_dashboard?)
        current_user.update(uuid: SecureRandom.uuid)
        cookies[:uuid] = current_user.uuid
      end 
      super
    end
  end

  private
  def update_login_terms_and_privacy_accepted_at   
  self.resource.update_attribute("login_terms_and_privacy_accepted_at", Time.now) if self.resource.login_terms_and_privacy_accepted_at.nil?
  end
```

This is what I see in logs -

```
 Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 104.143.209.101 at 2019-06-24 18:24:50 +0000

I, [2019-06-24T18:24:50.783420 #32598]  INFO -- : Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML

I, [2019-06-24T18:24:50.783508 #32598]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"F8BrJRihhHuNA2a8qe82MbXg6rq/sGSVtFaB3xqzHTMqTSEkU+kvQZNs1sLSLEhCRvH29bof8HgFsyANBuliJA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"su***@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "terms_and_condition"=>"1", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "g-recaptcha-response"=>"", "commit"=>"Log in"}

I, [2019-06-24T18:24:50.980455 #32598]  INFO -- : Redirected to https://gici.com/users/sign_in

I, [2019-06-24T18:24:51.064536 #32598]  INFO -- : 

Sent mail to su***@gmail.com (57.3ms)
```

The email sent in the last line of logs is on creation of duplicate user record.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did my answer work?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have this line of code

```
self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
```

and then after controller action you are calling

```
update_login_terms_and_privacy_accepted_at
```

which in turn calls

```
self.resource.update_attribute("login_terms_and_privacy_accepted_at", Time.now)
```

this will save that object into the database.

Note that https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute

validations in update_attribute are skipped so the object is saved without validations -> hence duplicate records.

Probably you only do validations on the model level. The most safe way is to enforce uniqueness on the database level. You can check how to do this for example in this link: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/validation-database-constraint-or-both

basically you would have to create a migration and add a unique constraint to your `users` table.